# IBM Content Navigator /jaxrs/p8/getDocument only return the first content element

Tags: p8

I want to use the IBM Content Navigator URL API, /jaxrs/p8/getDocument, to retrieve the content of a document object from P8. However, I found that this API only return the first content element. Is this a "design as is" or there is some tricks to work it arround. I have to use URL based API because I need to access P8 platform from a non-java/non-.NET platform

I followed the description in page 381 of the IBM Redbook 'Customizing and Extending IBM Content Navigator'